# PowerShell script to remove characters from files and folders

Tags: powershell

I am trying to recursively remove certain characters from files and folders using a PowerShell script. Below is the script that I have found, but it will only remove underscores from files, not folders. There are a few characters which will need to be removed, but I am fine with having a script for each character if need be. It does recursively change files in the folders, but no folders are 'fixed'.

Current PowerShell script:

```
'dir -Recurse | where {-not $_.PsIscontainer -AND $_.name -match "_"} | foreach {
        $New = $_.name.Replace("_","")
        Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru
    }'
```

Comment: remove `-Not $_.PsIscontainer -And` from the where condition and it will affect folders too

Comment: Check out [TN's Powershell Tips](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730953.aspx) for an explanation of that code. Main problem: PsIsContainer only returns true for directories (so with -not that is only returning files)

Comment: Thanks Paul, I am now able to change files and folders, but it does not appear to be recursing correctly.  The script will rename items in the current location but does not go into the nested folders.  If I run the script a second time it catches the first nested folders, the second time it goes one level deeper.  Any ideas on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments the core of your issue is that you are excluding folders with the `-Not $_.PsIscontainer` component of your `Where` block.

```powershell
dir -recurse | where {$_.name -match "_"} | ...
```

The second issue that you are having is most likely that since you are changing folder names the children you had previously inventoried with `dir`/`Get-ChildItem` would then have incorrect paths. One way to address this would be to process files first then folders.

```powershell
$filesandfolders = Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -match "_"} 
$filesandfolders | Where-Object {!$_.PsIscontainer}  |  foreach {
    $New=$_.name.Replace("_","")
    Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru -WhatIf
}
$filesandfolders | Where-Object {$_.PsIscontainer}  |  foreach {
    $New=$_.name.Replace("_","")
    Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru -WhatIf
}
```

By no means the prettiest solution but it would work. It processes all the files first, then the folders. Remove the `-Whatif`s when you are sure it would do what you expect

**Other characters**

You had mentioned there were other characters that you were looking to remove. That wouldn't be a tall order. You could be using regex for this so lets try that.

```powershell
$characters = "._"
$regex = "[$([regex]::Escape($characters))]"

$filesandfolders = Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -match $regex} 
$filesandfolders | Where-Object {!$_.PsIscontainer}  |  foreach {
    $New=$_.name -Replace $regex
    Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru -WhatIf
}
$filesandfolders | Where-Object {$_.PsIscontainer}  |  foreach {
    $New=$_.name -Replace $regex
    Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru -WhatIf
}
```

That would remove all of the periods and underscores from those files and folders.

Not tested but you might even be able to get it down to these few lines

```powershell
$characters = "._"
$regex = "[$([regex]::Escape($characters))]"

$filesandfolders = Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -match $regex} 
$filesandfolders | Where-Object {!$_.PsIscontainer} | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.name -Replace $regex) -PassThru -WhatIf
$filesandfolders | Where-Object {$_.PsIscontainer}  | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.name -Replace $regex) -PassThru -WhatIf
```

Comment: Actually, it is "PSIsContainer", not "PsIscontainer". Does case matter for property names?

Comment: @PeterMortensen No, it is not case sensitive.