# Powershell renaming files recursively, not renaming duplicates

Tags: powershell, recursion

I have some powershell code that is meant to take specific characters out of file names recursively. This works great, unless taking the characters out causes 2 files to match names in the same folder.

I found the Powershell here [PowerShell script to remove characters from files and folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105019/powershell-script-to-remove-characters-from-files-and-folders) but it doesn't solve the issue I am having.

```
$characters = "$#"
$regex = "[$([regex]::Escape($characters))]"

$filesandfolders = Get-ChildItem -recurse "D:\projects\filenameCleaner\TEST" | Where-Object {$_.name -match $regex} 
$filesandfolders | Where-Object {!$_.PsIscontainer}  |  foreach {
    $New=$_.name -Replace $regex
    Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru
}
$filesandfolders | Where-Object {$_.PsIscontainer}  |  foreach {
    $New=$_.name -Replace $regex
    Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru
}
```

I'm not very versed in Powershell yet and would love some help with this. I just want the script that, if it finds a duplicate, it should just add a (1) or (2) etc at the end, depending on how many there are.

Please don't just give me an answer, explain it so that I can learn what is happening

Answer (score 3):

I think the way to tackle this is to create a new PSOBJECT which contains your source and target paths. You can then use the Group-object to group on the target path which will give you a count which you can then use to determine which files will need a number suffix.

Something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse "D:\projects\filenameCleaner\TEST" | ? {!$_.PsIscontainer} | % {
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        source = $_.FullName
        target = ($_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($_.Name)) + ($_.Name -replace '[\$#]+', '') 
    }
} | Group-Object target | % {
    $g = $_.Group
    0..($g.Count - 1) | % {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            source = $g[$_].source
            target = $g[$_].target -replace '\.',  @('.', "($($_)).")[$_ -gt 0]
        }        
    }
} | % {Rename-Item -Path $_.source -NewName $_.Target}
```

The nice thing about doing it this way is that it can two, three or more duplcates

I have only done the code for files so you would need another version for folders.

Comment: Thank you, but this looks way more complicated then it needs to be to me. I'm not sure at all how this works

Comment: I think the way to understand what it is doing is to run it sections and study the output. Run it first from the beginning up to before the pipe before the `Group-Object`, then run it from the beginning but include the `Group-object`.The code is breaking your problem down into steps with each step becoming a pipe on the chain. Think of the steps like this 1) get the file list 2) remove the folders 3) capture the file path and the new file path 4) group on the new file path and count the duplicates 5) loop through the groups and add the count if needed 6) rename the files. Sounds simple to me.

Comment: Very nice approach Dave, I see a problem with duplicates from previous runs which wouldn't be included in the groups.

Comment: Good point - I suppose the simple way around that would be when capturing the target path in the first PSOBJECT would be to strip out the brackets and numbers so that the file would revert to it's original grouping, something like `-replace '\(\d+\)\.', '.'` should do it. It would mean that some duplicates would get renumbered, but I don't see that as issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by adding an if-statement that checks the new path

```
$characters = "$#}"
$regex = "[$([regex]::Escape($characters))]"
$path = "D:\projects\filenameCleaner\TEST"
$filesandfolders = Get-ChildItem -recurse $path | Where-Object {$_.name -match $regex} 
$filesandfolders | Where-Object {!$_.PsIscontainer}  |  foreach {
    $New=$_.name -Replace $regex
    $newPath = $path+"\"+$New
    $loop = 0
    while (Test-Path $newPath) {
        $loop = $loop + 1
        $basename = $_.basename -Replace $regex
        $New = $basename + " ("+$loop+")"+$_.extension
        $newPath = $path+"\"+$New
    }
    "Rename `""+$_.name+"`" to `""+$New+"`""
    Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru
}
$filesandfolders | Where-Object {$_.PsIscontainer}  |  foreach {
    $New=$_.name -Replace $regex
    $newPath = $path+"\"+$New
    $loop = 0
    while (Test-Path $newPath) {
        $loop = $loop + 1
        $basename = $_.basename -Replace $regex
        $New = $basename + " ("+$loop+")"+$_.extension
        $newPath = $path+"\"+$New
    }
    "Rename `""+$_.name+"`" to `""+$New+"`""
    Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru
}
```

-- Another update that handles the extensions separately when adding the number to the string for duplicates. I was having issues that the number would go onto the file name after the extension which is obviously a no-go

Comment: Suppose I had three files in folder called d$#ata.csv, da$#ta.csv and dat$#a.csv - how would your code handle that?

Comment: @DaveSexton you're totally right. I've fixed that I believe in my update, do yo see any other issues?

Comment: No seems fine now. Just a general comment that I think you need to get more into the spirit of Powershell. In Powershell you have all these cool features like pipes, ranges and string expansion. You don't need to all that  complex string concatenation. For instance your output line could be done like so: `"Rename \`"$($_.name)\`" to \`"$New\`""` or another alternative like this: `'Rename "{0}" to "{1}"' -f $_.name, $New`.